# vim: jump to yaml position

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I have pretty long YAML files to deal with (>5000 lines), most of them language files. When we get a bug report about a wrong translation, we get the path to this translation inside the yaml file, for example `en.main.widgets.products.header.title`.

As you can imagine, finding this specific path in a nested, and most of the time unsorted, YAML file is painful.

Is there a vim plugin, where I give a path to a command, and the cursor jumps to this location? If not, any recommendations about how to write one?

Comment: As far as existing plugins henrik/vim-yaml-flattener (https://github.com/henrik/vim-yaml-flattener) seems to be the closest match to what you are looking for.  You will likely need to use a special installation of vim, compiled with ruby support, to use the plugin as this is not standard.

Comment: Do you know [yq](https://yq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

Comment: actually why not just write a function which splits a string by `.` and search every word in the collection one after another?

Comment: Henrik of vim-yaml-flattener fame here! I've stopped using it and instead use https://github.com/henrik/vim-yaml-helper (my fork of https://github.com/lmeijvogel/vim-yaml-helper, changed to have unique command prefixes). You can use `:YamlGoToKey` to do e.g. `:YamlG main.widgets.products.header.title` to jump straight there. You can also run `:YamlF` (`:YamlFullPath`) when you're somewhere in the YAML document to see the full path to where you're at, and it's copied so you can paste it elsewhere. No need to flatten and unflatten the file.